# Android Fragments

Tags: java, android

I have a problem I have Three buttons on my activity and when click in one button I want to open a specific fragment.How can I do this?
This is my code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                if (bt1.isClickable()){
                    Fragment_one f1 = new Fragment_one();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, f1);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: So, exactly what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Shadab I done this but i got an error when I go to another fragment

Comment: I do the same thing than here for the other buttons

Comment: Post the error which you are getting

Comment: FragmentTransaction.commit();.I have this error when I go to another Fragment for the twice

Comment: What exactly is the error ?

Comment: post full stack trace, it's hard to help you with this much error lines ...

Comment: The error is not describ at well it is only subline the  fragmentTransaction.commit(); method

Comment: Process: com.example.toureamidou.cjb, PID: 29515
                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called

Comment: @AmidouFlorianTouré **copy all of the stack trace and paste into your question**. It still isn't clear where this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // use either changeFragment() or replaceFragment methods to switch between your fragments
            Fragment_one f1 = new Fragment_one();
            changeFragment(f1);
            // replaceFragment(f1);
        }
    });

// this method will add a fragment if it not exist or show it if exists
public void changeFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    String tag = fragment.getClass().getName();
    // Check if fragment was added already
    boolean alreadyAdded = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) != null;

    // hide all added fragments
    List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
    if (fragments != null) {
        for (Fragment f : fragments) {
            transaction.hide(f);
        }
    }

    // if the given fragment is added already just show it
    // if not then add it
    if (alreadyAdded) {
        transaction.show(fragment);
    } else {
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag);
        // add to back stack will store just added fragments
        transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}

// this method will replace current fragment with the given one
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    String tag = fragment.getClass().getName();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

You don't need to check if the button is clickable in onClick() because if it is not clickable the onClick() will not be called at all

Comment: @AmidouFlorianTouré if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

On your **OnClickListener** Method add this Simple code.

```
FragmentManager frgManager3 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    frgManager3.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentOne())
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

And you dont need to check if Button is Clickable or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
package iwannado.com.ormliteapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

    import android.widget.Button;


    public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
            bt1.setOnClickListener(this);
            bt2.setOnClickListener(this);
            bt3.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();
            switch (id){
                R.id.button1:
                replaceFragmentInActivity(new Fragment_one());
                break;
                R.id.button2:
                replaceFragmentInActivity(new Fragment_two());
                break;
                R.id.button3:
                replaceFragmentInActivity(new Fragment_three());
                break;
            }
        }
        public void replaceFragmentInActivity(Fragment fragment) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
```